# How to convert Uint8Array with byteOffset to Arraybuffer for HttpClient.post

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, arraybuffer, uint8array

How can I efficiently (no copy, only wrappers) convert a `Uint8Array` (`payload`) with a non-zero `byteOffset`
to a `ArrayBuffer` such that it can be sent binary-style with the Angular `HttpClient.post` method?

```
public post(requestUrl: string, payload: Uint8Array): Promise<Uint8Array> {

    return this.httpClient.post(url, payload, { responseType: 'arraybuffer', headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': "application/octet-stream" }) })
}
```